# Change of reference frame and change of basis

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

In special relativity we use the Lorentz transformations to change between frames of reference:

$$t'=\gamma (t-\frac{vx}{c^2})$$
$$x'=\gamma (x-vt)$$
$$y'=y$$
$$z'=z$$

which is equivalent to the matrix multiplication with $c=1$:

$$x^{\mu}=\Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu}x'^{\mu}$$

where $$\Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu}= \begin{pmatrix}\gamma & -v\gamma & 0 & 0 \\ -v\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I am trying to connect this to my understanding of tensors which I'm learning at the same time. When we transform between basis sets and look at how tensors transform accordingly (to figure out their type) is this mathematically what we're doing when we change between frames in special relativity with the Lorentz transformations?

And when we talk about the metric tensor in a vector space, $g_{ij}$, is this the same mathematical object as the Minkowski metric $\eta_{ij}$?

If there are any other obvious mathematical similarities that I'm missing I'd really appreciate them being pointed out. I'd much rather approach this mathematically first than from a physical perspective.

Comment: In some circumstances, you could have that $g_{ij}=\eta_{ij}$, but most authors I'm familiar with use $g$ to denote a generic metric and $\eta$ for the Minkowski one.

Comment: But mathematically they are just the same object? Minkowski spacetime has a special place in Physics because it's a satisfying model of the universe we live in but mathematically the Lorentz transformations are the same as a "change of basis" in tensor analysis and the Minkowski metric is just another metric tensor for a particular space?

Comment: Yes, they have the same properties, so they can be used in exactly the same way. As you said, $\eta$ has particular use in physics due to its description of flat spacetime

Comment: Which tensors are you referring to when you say "When we transform between basis sets and look at how tensors transform accordingly.."? Or are you referring to an arbitrary tensor?

Comment: I'm referring to an arbitrary tensor.

Comment: That is actually the more burning question I have here. When we classify the covarient and contravarient valency of a tensor we perform some arbitrary transformation of the basis represented for instance by a matrix $S$, and look at how the representation of the tensor itself changes in terms of this same matrix and it's inverse.

My question is whether this arbitrary change of basis used to define tensors is mathematically the same as the arbitrary change between coordinates systems in frame of reference changes.

Comment: The Lorentz transform is not a tensor - it's a mapping between frames which preserves the origin. For instance, the tensor $T=T^{ij}_{k}du^{k}\otimes \frac{\partial}{{\partial u^{i}}}\otimes \frac{\partial}{{\partial u^{j}}}$ is the direct products of a form $du^{k}$ and vectors $\frac{\partial}{{\partial u^{j}}}$ and transforms like a tensor. Typically, we denote the tensor by it's tensor coefficient, namely, $T^{ij}_{k}$.

Comment: Opps - in the comment above, I didn't mean direct product - I meant tensor product.